# Yellowish-gold double bars (lieutenant's bars?) on Star Wars characters?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification

During *The Clone Wars* series, we see Ahsoka Tano's headband has two yellowish-gold double bars at the temples (looks like lieutenant's bars):

[image: Screenshot of Ahsoka Tano in 'The Clone Wars']

We see something similar in *The Mandalorian* on Bo-Katan Kryze's headband:

[image: Screenshot of Bo-Katan Kryse in 'The Mandalorian']

The third time we see these is in *Ahsoka* but this time it is Sabine Wren's Mandalorian armor:

[image: Screenshot of Sabine Wren in 'Ahsoka']

Is there a description of what these are and their purpose?

Comment: Apparently they light up; https://www.reddit.com/r/clonewars/comments/jp8ek3/comment/gcgotux/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3. I strongly suspect they're just there to help the audience spot the goodies more easily

Comment: [Magnetic clips to hold her goggles in place](https://64.media.tumblr.com/2ac03368f6e97d339f1e02418d91cec0/23d1914bd5c77503-ef/s640x960/6f7344f8a0b47d21e304a965cb1d5ed729d175a7.gifv), maybe?

Comment: There's a couple of similarly shaped cut-outs on Boba Fett's chestplate too, albeit with some red blinkies instead of yellow. I think this shape it just meant to be a visual nod to that feature; a signifier of Mandalorian armor tech, with no specific function in mind (see also the random bits of greebly-tech often sewn into pieces of costuming in the OT.)  Any yes, Ahsoka's outfit is Mandalorian; note the hexagonal diamond shape on the chest which is an oft repeated motif in their armor, wardrobe & architecture.